Java NIO readable selectionKey always exist in selectedKeys
I'm new to Java NIO. Here is a toy tcp server I wrote. The problem is that a readable selectionKey is always available in the selectionKeys of the selector even after I remove it from the selectedKeys. In my opinion, after the selectionKey is removed from the iterator of the selectedKey set, it won't appear again. However, if you run the program, one readable selectionKey always exists in the selectedKey set.

Server code


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * @author ethan.tan
 * @date 2024/06/07 16:45
 **/
public class TcpServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(~(SelectionKey.OP_WRITE | SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT | SelectionKey.OP_READ));
        Selector selector = Selector.open();
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = null;
        try {
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(885);
            ServerSocket socket = serverSocketChannel.socket();
            socket.bind(socketAddress);
            serverSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);

            serverSocketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
            while (selector.select() > 0) {
                if (null == selector.selectedKeys()) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(selector.selectedKeys().size());
                Iterator<SelectionKey> selectionKeyIterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
                while (selectionKeyIterator.hasNext()) {
                    SelectionKey selectionKey = selectionKeyIterator.next();
                    if (selectionKey.isAcceptable()) {
                        ServerSocketChannel channel = (ServerSocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
                        System.out
                            .println("someone " + channel.socket().getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " is accetped");
                        SocketChannel socketChannel = channel.accept();
                        if (socketChannel != null) {
                            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                            // socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                            socketChannel.register(selector,
                                SelectionKey.OP_READ | SelectionKey.OP_CONNECT);
                        }
                    } else if (selectionKey.isReadable()) {
                        System.out.println("is readable");
                        SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel)selectionKey.channel();
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(24);
                        while (socketChannel.read(byteBuffer) > 0) {
                            byteBuffer.flip();
                            System.out.println(byteBuffer.limit());
                            System.out.println(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.decode(byteBuffer).toString());
                            byteBuffer.clear();
                        }

                    }
                    selectionKeyIterator.remove();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("wrong with io exception");
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (selector != null && selector.isOpen()) {
                selector.close();
            }
            if (serverSocketChannel != null && serverSocketChannel.isOpen()) {
                serverSocketChannel.close();
            }
        }
    }
}


Client code

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport;

/**
 * @author ethan.tan
 * @date 2024/06/07 16:07
 **/
public class TcpClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] hostByte = "127.0.0.1".getBytes();
//        InetAddress inet4Address;
//        try {
//            inet4Address = Inet4Address.getByAddress(hostByte);
//        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
//            throw new RuntimeException(e);
//        }
        SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 885);
        SocketChannel socketChannel = null;
        try {
            socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(socketAddress);
            socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) {

            }
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(240);
            byteBuffer.put("Hello Kurumi".getBytes());
            byteBuffer.flip();
            byteBuffer.clear();
            socketChannel.write(byteBuffer);
            socketChannel.shutdownOutput();
            socketChannel.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

I tried to remove the readable selectionKey from the selectedKey set. It did work. However, the selectedKey set is not empty in the next loop and a readable selection key is found again. I don't know why this happens.


If read() returns -1 it means end of stream, so you should close the channel. You are ignoring this case. 2. if (null == selector.selectedKeys()) can never be true. Don't write pointless code. 3. configureBlocking(false) followed by connect() followed by while (!socketChannel.finishConnect()) is entirely equivalent to connect() followed by configureBlocking(false) but without the spin loop: not that you need non-blocking mode in this client at all. 4. shutdownOutput() before close() is redundant.


Thank you! I know you know you are completely correct. But still, really appreciate for your help. I wanna take your comment as accepted answer and close the question.
BTW, currently I'm learning Java nio and related stuff. Do you have any suggestions for me? Hope this doesn't bother you.

Sure, buy my book ;-) Fundamental Networking in Java, Springer 2006.

You are amazing. Thx for help. I will get this book later :) I can't believe that you even published a book?!

Two actually, another on RMI.

I'm pretty sure I'll have more questions when I read your book later. Thank you again for helping me out.
